# I got a trouble when I using ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, authorization

Here are 2 cookie response in my project function:

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
_httpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
var cookie_new=new HttpCookie(new HttpCookie("test","vote"));
_httpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

The project is using  for user authorization, but when I using the first cookie sending AJAX[type='post'] to an action, I take an error msg says

> "A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid.".

However the another one is success. 
I do not understand what the problem is.

Comment: Removed tags from title; acronym capitalization; grammar; noise reduction; layout.

Answer (score 0):

The ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute must be added to the action in your controller, like so:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
...
}
```

But you must also provide a control on the form to hold the anti-forgery token within the View by adding:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

If you examine the page source of the rendered view, then you should see a `__RequestVerificationToken` in a hidden `input`, along with its value.

Comment: that what i do,but not useful. After add the first cookie the actions in this page were in error.And it want be working unless i remove [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] from action .